# Can't bind to property of one control in a DataTrigger to other control in different grids

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding, wpf-controls

I have two controls in this example but in the real application i have many more whick depending of the value of the property Content of a Label in Grid one (for example), some other Labels, TextBoxes, TextBlocks and Buttons will be Visible or Collapsed in Grid two (for example).

But to simplify my problem i will have a simplified example...

```
<Grid Name="gridOne">
    <Label Content="{Binding Collection.Name}" Name="lblCaption"/>
</Grid>

<Grid Name="gridTwo">
    <Label Content="My Label" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <Label.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=lblCaption, Path=Content}" Value="Employers">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Label.Style>
    </Label>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding EmployerName}" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=lblCaption, Path=Content}" Value="Employers">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

I know that this won't work too if i set the property Visibility as Collapsed for default in control but i have many collections and i don't think that having one DataTrigger for each Collection is good way to achieve it. Anyway one problem comes when binding controls in different grids and other in handling the property Visibility in a good way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local value takes [precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) over style triggers. Move the visibility intialization inside the style as:

```
<Label Content="My Label">
  <Label.Style>                    
    <Style TargetType="Label">
      <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=lblCaption, Path=Content}" Value="Employers">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Label.Style>
</Label>
```